# Identifying with regexes and Python the title of a particular paragraph containing an unique word (and French Judges)

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing some data analysis over the judge appointment system in France, and using some code to do so. But I've run into a regex problem.

My data, is made of a big list of courts and judges appointments.

Here's an example list :

> Appellate Court of Paris
>
> Blabla about the jugdge : Mr Dominique Martin, blahblahblah Blabla
>   about the judge : Ms Jeanne Truc
>
> District Court of Paris
>
> Blabla about the jugdge : Mr François Dupont, blahblahblah Blabla
>   about the jugdge : Mr Jean Dupuis, blahblahblah Blabla about the
>   jugdge : Ms Marguerite Lorem, blahblahblah
>
> District Court of Lyon
>
> Blabla about the judge : Ms Lorena Ipsum, blablabh

And there a big lot of these, district and appellate courts mingled. Usually, after a city appellate court, comes the district one.

(*For the french guys reading this, I'm translating "Tribunal de grande instance" to "District Court" and "Cour d'appel" to "Appellate Court" it's easier to understand if everything is in English*)

And then I need a list of the judges by the courts their in.

To achieve that, I started doing a regex using good ol' python 3. First I get a list of all the judges thanks to the Mr and Mrs (well it's french so M. and Mme. ). And then, iterating over each judge in this list to find where the hell their being appointed. I wrote something like that :

```
court = re.findall(r'(District Court of.+?|Appelate Court of.+?)\n.+?'+ judge, appointments, re.S)
```

The "judge" var is then the name of the current judge I'm seeking and "appointments" the list I'm regexing on. Dotall flag is on, and if you don't know python, forget about the 'r' before the pattern, it's just about how to interpret special chars in the string following.

(I've also tried using re.search, but i think re.findall is better for spotting bugs)

And the result is always the first one in the list (for instance : Appellate Court of Paris)... just as if it was working as a greedy request, even if I flagged every quatifier with the '?' that in python identifies the quantifier as non-greedy.

(I'm a law student, not a CS one, I beg for forgiveness if I'm doing something utterly wrong there).

Note: The original list i'm parsing : http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000022472292 (BEWARE that's an UGLY french government website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current regex is that even with lazy quantifiers the match will occur as early in the string as the regex allows.  For example `re.search('A+?B', 'AAB')` would match the entire string 'AAB', it would not move on to the second 'A' so that it matches as few as possible.

So basically, you get the name of a court and then search through the string until you find the first occurrence of the judge's name, even if that means you are entering a new court section.  Here are two good options for preventing this:

- First split `appointments` at each new court, and then search each court for the judge name individually.

or...

- Add a negative lookahead to your regex so it will fail if it reaches a new court name before the name of the judge.

Here is an example with a negative lookahead:

```
appointments = """\
COURT A
...
COURT B
...
COURT C
Judge Judy"""

>>> re.findall(r'^COURT[^\n]+(?:.(?!^COURT))+Judge Judy', appointments, re.S | re.M)
['COURT C\nJudge Judy']
```

Your current code would be similar to the following:

```
>>> re.findall(r'COURT.+?\n.+?Judge Judy', appointments, re.S)
['COURT A\n...\nCOURT B\n...\nCOURT C\nJudge Judy']
```

Comment: Great ! I never understood the negative lookahead thing. Now it's clear and yes it works perfectly... and faster than I thought (takes seconds to process the whole list). 

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) to parse the html:

```
import lxml.html as LH
import re

url='http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000022472292'
doc=LH.parse(url)
data=(p.text_content() for p in doc.xpath('//p'))
next(data) # Skip the paragraph before the first court
result={}
for court,text in zip(*[data]*2):
    court=court.strip()  
    names=re.findall(r'((?:M\.|Mme)[^,]+),',text)
    result[court]=names

print(result)
```

yields [this result](http://paste.ubuntu.com/745318/).

The page that you linked to is actually fairly organized. (At least, I've seen a lot worse! ;). Every court is in its own `<p>` tag, and the following `<p>` tag contains the text listing all the people. So if you use an HTML parser to find all the `<p>` tags, you can sort out the courts and the people in short order.

---

The [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) `zip(*[iter(...)]*2)` was used to step through the `<p>`-tag data two `<p>`-tags at a time.

Comment: Thanks for this elegant answer, and I'll try to use some of it in my next code. The only problem is that not all the data I have is digitized and online. I have also a lot of .txt files with the raw data (and some of the older shit is OCRized from scans... forcing me to do a lot of hand corrections). So html parsing will only work for the last 2 decades of data while I'm working on almost 7. 

Indeed the version you posted before this one was more helpful for me :-), luckily I've copied it before your edit :D

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is somewhat complicated.

You might want to try it like this:
Save this file in text format (without the html) first. Copying the text from the browser into a text editor will work. Then loop through the file line by line, using the following (untested) python. In the end the dict appointments will contain the location of each judge.

```
court = ''
appointments = {}
for line in open(yourfile):
    court_match = re.match(court_pattern, line)
    if court_match:
        # It is a new court
        court = court_match.group(1)
    else:
        judge_match = re.match(judge_pattern, line)
        if judge_match:
            judge = judge_match.group(1)
            appointments[judge] = court
for judge, appointment in appointments.items():
    print("Judge {0} is located at {1}".format(judge, appointment))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's indeed what I was trying to hack (unsuccessfully) before learning about negative lookaheads. It works, but seems to be not as fast as the F-J answer. Anyway, your right that sometimes it's better to scrap everything we did before and try to think differently. 

Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

The principle from which you start is doubly not good.

### First,

run this code:

```
import urllib

url = 'http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000022472292'

sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
ch = sock.read()
sock.close()

print '\n'.join(str(i)+'  '+repr(line)
                for i,line in enumerate(ch.splitlines(True)))
```

and you'll obtain:

```
..........
502  '<p>\n'
503  "<br/>Cour d'appel de Chamb\xc3\xa9ry</p>\n"
504  '<p>\n'
505  "<br/> Conseill\xc3\xa8re : Mme Martine IMBERTON-VARACHE, vice-pr\xc3\xa9sidente au tribunal de grande instance d'Annecy.<br/> Vice-pr\xc3\xa9sident plac\xc3\xa9 aupr\xc3\xa8s du premier pr\xc3\xa9sident : M. Serge BEUGNON, juge au tribunal de grande instance d'Annecy.<br/> Vice-procureure plac\xc3\xa9e aupr\xc3\xa8s du procureur g\xc3\xa9n\xc3\xa9ral : Mme Rosabelle MOSCATO, juge d'instruction au tribunal de grande instance de Thonon-les-Bains.</p>\n"
506  '<p>\n'
507  "<br/>Tribunal de grande instance d'Albertville</p>\n"
508  '<p>\n'
509  "<br/> Vice-pr\xc3\xa9sidente charg\xc3\xa9e de l'application des peines : Mme Nathalie HERMITTE-CHEYNIS, substitute du procureur de la R\xc3\xa9publique pr\xc3\xa8s le tribunal de grande instance de Chamb\xc3\xa9ry.<br/> Vice-procureure de la R\xc3\xa9publique : Mme Nathalie FARIN, \xc3\xa9pouse PAROT, substitute du procureur de la R\xc3\xa9publique pr\xc3\xa8s le tribunal de grande instance de Chamb\xc3\xa9ry.<br/> Substitute du procureur de la R\xc3\xa9publique, \xc3\xa0 compter du 1er novembre 2010 : Mme Marie GUERIN, substitute du procureur de la R\xc3\xa9publique pr\xc3\xa8s le tribunal de grande instance de Dole.</p>\n"
510  '<p>\n'
........
```

We see that each portion concerning a "Tribunal de grande instance" or a "Cour d'appel" is naturally delimited inside the following tags:

```
<p>\n
<br/> ..... </p>\n
<p>\n
<br/> ..... </p>\n
```

Hence this code to answer to your question:

```
import urllib

url = 'http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000022472292'
sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
ch = sock.read()
sock.close()

import re

pat = ("(?:Tribunal *de *grande *instance|Cour *d'appel) *(?:d[eu] +|d' *)"
       "(.+?)</p>\n"
       "<p>\n"
       ".+?%s.*?</p>\n")
for name in ('CACHET','GIROT','DELUMEAU','BLANC','MOUR','DELTOUR','KARKI'):
    print name,re.findall(pat % name,ch)
```

result

```
CACHET ['M\xc3\xa2con']
GIROT ['Douai', 'Lille']
DELUMEAU ['Meaux']
BLANC ['Cr\xc3\xa9teil', 'Troyes', 'Basse-Terre<br/>Tribunal de grande instance de Basse-Terre']
MOUR ['Papeete<br/>Tribunal de premi\xc3\xa8re instance de Papeete']
DELTOUR []
KARKI []
```

.

But we see that there's an incongruity in the portions concerning Basse-Terre and  Papeete.
Runing the following code shows all the incongruities:

```
print '\n'.join(repr(h) for h in re.findall('<p>\n<br/>.*?Tribunal.*?</p>\n',ch)
                if len(h)<250)
print
print
print '\n'.join(repr(h) for h in re.findall('<p>\n<br/>.*?Cour.*?</p>\n',ch)
                if len(h)<250)
```

The condition `if len(h)<250` is to not keep the part containing the names for Paris, because there is the word "Cour" in it and it makes the regex catching this part containing names (we only want titeles)

it produces:

```
'<p>\n<br/>Tribunal de grande instance de Paris</p>\n'
"<p>\n<br/>Tribunal de grande instance d'Auxerre</p>\n"
'<p>\n<br/>Tribunal de grande instance de Bobigny</p>\n'
................
.............
'<p>\n<br/>Tribunal de grande instance de Toulouse</p>\n'
"<p>\n<br/>Cour d'appel de Basse-Terre<br/>Tribunal de grande instance de Basse-Terre</p>\n"
'<p>\n<br/>Tribunal de grande instance de Pointe-\xc3\xa0-Pitre</p>\n'
'<p>\n<br/>Tribunal de grande instance de Cayenne</p>\n'
'<p>\n<br/>Tribunal de grande instance de Fort-de-France</p>\n'
'<p>\n<br/>Tribunal de grande instance de Saint-Denis de La R\xc3\xa9union</p>\n'
'<p>\n<br/>Tribunal de grande instance de Saint-Pierre de La R\xc3\xa9union</p>\n'
"<p>\n<br/>Cour d'appel de Papeete<br/>Tribunal de premi\xc3\xa8re instance de Papeete</p>\n"
"<p>\n<br/>Tribunal sup\xc3\xa9rieur d'appel de Mamoudzou</p>\n"
'<p>\n<br/>Tribunal de premi\xc3\xa8re instance de Mamoudzou</p>\n'


"<p>\n<br/>Cour d'appel de Paris</p>\n"
"<p>\n<br/>Cour d'appel de Versailles</p>\n"
"<p>\n<br/>Cour d'appel d'Agen</p>\n"
.........
..........
"<p>\n<br/>Cour d'appel de Toulouse</p>\n"
"<p>\n<br/>Cour d'appel de Basse-Terre<br/>Tribunal de grande instance de Basse-Terre</p>\n"
"<p>\n<br/>Cour d'appel de Fort-de-France</p>\n"
"<p>\n<br/>Cour d'appel de Saint-Denis de La R\xc3\xa9union</p>\n"
"<p>\n<br/>Cour d'appel de Papeete<br/>Tribunal de premi\xc3\xa8re instance de Papeete</p>\n"
```

Then, we also see that there aren't only "Tribunal de grande instance" and "Cour d'appel" to search but also "Tribunal de première instance" and "Tribunal supérieur d'appel" .

The regex's pattern must be modified.

.

It could be:

```
pat = ("(?:Tribunal *(?:de.+?instance|supérieur *d'appel)|Cour *d'appel) *"
       "(?:d[ue] +|d' *)"
       "(?!.*?[<>].*?</p>)(.+?)</p>\n"
       "<p>\n"
       ".+?%s.*?</p>\n")
for name in ('CACHET','GIROT','DELUMEAU','BLANC','MOUR','DELTOUR','KARKI'):
    print name,re.findall(pat1 % name,ch)
```

that correctly produces ***** :

```
CACHET ['M\xc3\xa2con']
GIROT ['Douai', 'Lille']
DELUMEAU ['Meaux']
BLANC ['Cr\xc3\xa9teil', 'Troyes', 'Basse-Terre']
MOUR ['Papeete']
DELTOUR ['Mamoudzou']
KARKI ['Mamoudzou']
```

***** : PROVIDED that the encoding of the code is `-*- encoding: utf8 -*-` because the web page concerned is encoded in UTF8 (see the automatically detected nature of the set of characters of the page [here](http://www.validome.org/validate))

.

But I prefer the following pattern, that doesn't require a particular encoding for the code:

```
pat = ("(?:Tribunal|Cour).+(?:d[eu] +|d' *)(.+?)</p>\n"
       "<p>\n"
       ".+?%s.*?</p>\n")
for name in ('CACHET','GIROT','DELUMEAU','BLANC','MOUR','DELTOUR','KARKI'):
    print name,re.findall(pat % name,ch)
```

Here, it is important that `.+` just after `(?:Tribunal|Cour)` is not followed by a **?**  ( this greedy `.+` can't go after the final `\n` anyway), otherwise the result would be :

```
CACHET ['grande instance de M\xc3\xa2con']
GIROT ['appel de Douai', 'grande instance de Lille']
DELUMEAU ['grande instance de Meaux']
BLANC ['grande instance de Cr\xc3\xa9teil', 'grande instance de Troyes', 'appel de Basse-Terre<br/>Tribunal de grande instance de Basse-Terre']
MOUR ['appel de Papeete<br/>Tribunal de premi\xc3\xa8re instance de Papeete']
DELTOUR ['appel de Mamoudzou']
KARKI ['premi\xc3\xa8re instance de Mamoudzou']
```

.

Note that there is also
**Inspection générale des services judiciaires**
and
**Administration centrale**
as "places" in the web page, not only cities.

.

.

### Secondly,

using a correct algorithm you can analyze the page and put all the data in a data structure that will be asked each time you want, instead of making a specific search again each time in the whole page:

```
pat = ("(?:Tribunal|Cour).+(?:d[eu] +|d' *)(.+?)</p>\n"
       "<p>\n"
       "(<br/>.*?(?=<br/>|</p>))+</p>\n")
regx = re.compile('M(?:me +|elle +|\. +)([^,])')

gen = ((mat.group(1),regx.findall(mat.group(2)))
        for mat in re.finditer(pat,ch))

from collections import defaultdict
di = defaultdict(list)

for place,li in gen:
    for el in li:
        di[el].append(place)

dikeys = di.keys()
dikeys.sort(key = lambda x: x.split()[-1])

print '\n'.join(('\n%-38s : %s' if i%5==0 else '%-38s : %s') % (k,' '.join(di[k]))
                for i,k in enumerate(dikeys) )
```

Note: `d[eu]+` is to catch correctly "Tribunal de grande instance du Mans"

**di** contains the places for each person's name.

This code displays:

```
Julie ACHARD                           : Bourges
Julien ADROIT                          : Béthune
Sophie ALEKSIC                         : Rennes
Vincent ANIERE                         : Foix
Maxime ANTIER                          : Nantes

François ANTONA                       : Orléans
Lionel ASCENSI                         : Angers
Anne-Elisabeth AUDIT                   : Coutances
Youssef BADR                           : Meaux
Marie BAHUON                           : Saint-Brieuc

Aude BELLAN                            : Amiens
Julie BELTOISE                         : Lorient
Camille BLANCO                         : Basse-Terre
Aude BLONDE                            : Castres
Florent BOITARD                        : Cambrai

Pauline BONNECARRERE                   : Tulle
..............
....................
```